# Get-AzureRmResourceGroup not returning resources from current subscription

Tags: powershell, azure

If I run

```
Get-AzureSubscription -Current
```

I get:

```
SubscriptionId            : a*<guid>
SubscriptionName          : Development                         
Environment               : AzureCloud                          
DefaultAccount            : t*<guid>          
IsDefault                 : True                                
IsCurrent                 : True                                
TenantId                  : 4*<guid>
```

Then I run:

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup
```

And neither of the two resources returned are in that subscription, of which there should many, according to the portal:

```
ResourceGroupName : Default-SQL-NorthCentralUS
Location          : northcentralus
ProvisioningState : Succeeded
Tags              :
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/0*<guid>*e/resourceGroups/Default-SQL-NorthCentralUS

ResourceGroupName : Default-Web-NorthCentralUS
Location          : northcentralus
ProvisioningState : Succeeded
Tags              :
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/0*<guid>*e/resourceGroups/Default-Web-NorthCentralUS
```

These are coming from another subscription I have, but as you can see, isn't the current one.

Why isn't `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup` getting the resource groups in the current subscription, and now do I fix this?

My Azure module is version 0.9.11 and AzureRM is version 1.0.1.
I also don't have access to `Switch-AzureMode` or `Get-AzureResourceGroup`

Comment: Just to clarify on this: Get-AzureSubscription belongs to the ASM module (azure), and Get-AzureRmResourceGroup belongs to the ARM (azurerm) module. They are completely isolated and do not share sessions. You were probably logged in to another subscription with the AzureRM module.

Comment: Indeed I was. Same account, different selected subscription.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to use

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId a*<guid>
```

Thanks to [Michael Rodger](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ed3f6084-7a62-48b3-b5fe-01987e9b0517/azurermresourcegroup-pulling-resources-from-a-different-subscription?forum=azurescripting) for providing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the context using below command if you have multiple subscriptions:

```
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionName "Name"
```